# JQuery updating data- attribute

Tags: jquery, dom

Consider the following example of a photo album.

The first page and last page of the album are half the size of the spread of the album. I set the `attr('data-width')` and `attr('data-width_correct')` for comparison

***For Example -- checkImageDimesions()***

```
//Define if first or last page
if($(this).is(':first-child') || $(this).is(':last-child'))
{
    $(this).find('img').attr('data-height_correct' , maxHeight);
    $(this).find('img').attr('data-width_correct' , maxWidth / 2);  
} else{
    $(this).find('img').attr('data-height_correct' , maxHeight);
    $(this).find('img').attr('data-width_correct' , maxWidth);  
}
```

This works as expected, updating the data- with the correct values. My next step is if the `width > width_correct` I want to add a class of resize.

```
if($(this).find('img').data('width') > $(this).find('img').data('width_correct'))
{

     $(this).addClass('resize');
}
```

The calling of this function happens on the success of jQuery .sortable(). On first sort this works correctly, however on subsequent sorts, the initial image that is not sized correctly retains the `.resize` and any new image that would return false on `width > width_correct`does not get assigned `resize`

**Sortable**

```
$("#sortable").sortable(
{
success: function(){checkImageDimension()} 
}
```

Comment: please read this: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/when-to-use-attr-vs-data

Comment: @cept0 This is exactly what I was looking for -- would be great answer!

Comment: Thanks - I've posted a quote below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Attaching object data (something that's not a simple string, number,
>   or boolean) to a DOM node will often cause memory leaks in Internet
>   Explorer. That's because DOM nodes are not native Javascript objects
>   in IE, so it doesn't understand how to garbage collect things that are
>   attached to them.
>
> If you just need a simple flag or number on a DOM node you can use
>   either attr("x_mycount", 1) or just set a property on the DOM node
>   using this.x_mycount instead. (Be careful choosing the attribute or
>   property name since you're in the DOM namespace and you could clobber
>   something if you're not careful.) It's safest to use .data() though.

Source: [forum.jquery.com/topic/when-to-use-attr-vs-data](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/when-to-use-attr-vs-data)

Answer (score 0):

To update data attributes you just add a second parameter to the data function.

```
$('#elementID').data('width-correct', '400');
```

That's it, and it will update.